# How to create a CSV file in python that can be saved in memory?

Tags: python, django, excel, csv

I'm creating a CSV file in django that when you got to a url it downloads the CSV file, it works great the only thing is that I would like that when the the file is being written it's stored in memory and not in hard disk. How do you do this with the import csv

This is for django that uses list to create the csv

```
def data_feed_file(request):
    open_publications = self.get_publications(user_context)

    with open('facebook_feed.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        filewriter.writerow(['id', 'title','description'])
        for op_pub in open_publications:
            filewriter.writerow([op_pub.id, op_pub.name, str(op_pub.description)])

    with open('facebook_feed.csv', 'rb') as myfile:
        response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=facebook_feed.csv'

    return response
```

Comment: You want the client to download the csv into memory?

Comment: `io.StringIO` ? But be aware that You must store soewhere the reference to this object and don't close it, or the gc will remove this from memory.

Comment: No I want the client to dowload the file but while it's being wirtten to be saved in memeory and not in hard disk

Comment: did you check the documentation for csv? like csv.reader?

Comment: Or even the Django's own documentation, which has a [specific section on outputting CSV files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-csv/#outputting-csv-with-django) which covers this exact use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the csv file in a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=dataframe) DataFrame. Like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('url_to_csv')
```

Then the csv is read by the pandas library and you don't have to save it to a drive.